# What is the difference between a design matrix and a "factor loading" matrix?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, linear-model

I realise this is probability a naive question, but what exactly is the difference between your standard design matrix $X$ in

$$y = X\beta + \epsilon$$

and a "factor loading" matrix $\Lambda$

$$y = \Lambda F + \epsilon$$

Where $F$ is an "unobserved random vector" according to Wikipedia. How is this different to simply treating the unknown $\beta$ as an unobserved random variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The design matrix contains *observed* covariates/predictors for which we estimate the regression coefficients $\beta$. The loadings matrix $\Lambda$ contains parameters which need to be estimated for the *unobserved* factors $F$.

If you want to make the analogy, the factors $F$ play the role of $X$ with the important distinction that $X$ is observed, whereas as $F$ is unobserved, and $\Lambda$ is analogous to $\beta$ because are parameters that need to be estimated.